# Concatenating single quote in where clause to a variable in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2017

I have a `VARCHAR` variable declared which I want to use in a where clause to search results with a specific phone number.

```
DECLARE @Phone VARCHAR(50) 
SET @Phone = 075000000

SELECT  * 
FROM my_table
WHERE phone = ''' + @Phone + '''
```

but it does not return any result. It works when I use `WHERE phone = '075000000'`
. I tried also `WHERE phone = '''' + @Phone + ''''` and `WHERE phone = CHAR(39) + @Phone + CHAR(39)` but still no results.

Also tried to declare `@Phone as NUMERIC` and converting it to string `CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @Phone)` but still same issue.

phone column is a `NVARCHAR(50), not null` .

Comment: What about `SET @Phone = '075000000'` and then `WHERE phone = @phone`? Us humans when talking to the computer have to tell the computer something is a string by putting quotes around it. But when you use a variable there is no such need. It already knows its a string.

Comment: @JNevill I cannot use the first one; single quotes need to be added in a second step or in the where clause.  We get phone number as it is without single quotes. ```WHERE phone = @phone``` this still does not work. No results.

Comment: You are searching for the *literal string* `' + @Phone + '` - you need `where phone = @Phone`

Comment: ```where phone = @Phone```  should work logically but it does not work on the database I am working on which is built by professional people.
[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b69746d2fc51e7dee0533f0b018a3ff1) it works but not on our DB.

Comment: Why do single quotes need to be added? That seems VERY strange.

Comment: *it does not work on the database I am working on* - you've tagged Sql Server - it sounds like there's some cruicial information missing from your question.

Comment: It is strange. That is what I do not understand. I confirmn, the DB is on SQL Server.

Comment: It looks like you are using a _tool_, provided by Professional People®, that attempts to "sanitize" the input before allowing the database engine to handle it. Can you confirm that you are not using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) to enter your queries? What does `select @@Version;` return?

Comment: @HABO - Yes I am using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS). 

```Select @@Version``` returns ```Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU29) (KB5010786) - 14.0.3436.1 (X64) ``` on ```Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3 <x64> (Build 9600)```

Comment: It is an ```Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit)```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
DECLARE @Phone VARCHAR(50) 
SET @Phone = '''075000000'''

SELECT  * 
FROM my_table
WHERE phone = @Phone
```

Comment: As mentioned above `SET @Phone = '075000000'` does work but we want to be able to add single quotes afterwards.

Comment: I edited the value. Is that you want or can you provide me the value exactly you want

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
DECLARE @Phone NVARCHAR(50) 
SET @Phone = '075000000'

SELECT  * 
FROM my_table
WHERE phone = @Phone
```

[@Stu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15332650/stu) has already provided the answer and the explanation in the comments section.